# Create complex configurable product

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm novice with in Magento, i'm creating a store hardware & workshop tools. Some products are specific attributes like: code, reference, dimension. I want to display a product with all this attributes in product page (see  link attachmenent). What should I doing please ??

http://i60.tinypic.com/o0p0qv.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look's like you have to create configuration product.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

First create simple product with related attribute and then on base of it create configuration product.